# how to Connect BlueTooth device running Serial Port Profile (SPP from command line

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

I have the device with Blue-Tooth on the board. The firmware in the device runs Serial Port Profile (SPP) stack on it.

It works well when I connect to this device from my laptop by means of Blueman applet.
This applet involves asking me:

> PinCode, 
>   Pairing my laptop and device, 
>    creating
>   /dev/rfcommX device file, which I use to trnasmit with the device.

So, it works well,

BUT I need to be able to organize this connection from command line.
I've read different forums, but could not get nor my understanding neither working recipe.

I need the description how to do this. Could you please write here your advices?
Also, this Blueman applet crashes my Ubuntu 13.04 at Dell Latitude E6430 from time to time (when I click to connect Serial Port in there).

This is a screen of Blueman applet, just in case
[image]

I believe the command line solution I need should at least do this:
1. Ask to input a PinCode to Pair with device.
2. Create /dev/rfcommX device file